# Calling web api from xamarin android app

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, call

I have an MSSQL database and a web api over it. 
I can call the api from another pc in the same network with the server ip address, so the IIS Express config allows the connection, the firewall is open and the api is working.
I can call an open weather api from the android app, so my code is working.

But from the android app, when I call my web api, it throws timeout exception.

My client code is:

```
private async Task<string> FetchWebApiHttpClient(string baseUrl, string path)
    {

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string result = "";
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Show the base url used. Tell where your Android app is running? Somewhere at see?

Comment: Are you calling HTTPS url?

Comment: No HTTPS, my base url is http://192.168.0.44:50476/  I tried with host name, and both was fine from another pc from the same network, but nothing from android app.

Comment: @greenaps What do u mean about where my android app running? No sd card, and same network.

Comment: Now with hostname I got System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.NameResolutionFailure And with IP nothing.